# GAWK concat variables in FOR

Tags: bash, awk, gnu, gawk

My current GAWK scripts takes phrases file, and creates array of regex patterns, then splits each line by \t character and loop first 10 columns of each row, then it checks if it contain at least one phrase from patterns array, if it does, it skips the line and do not print it into document.

Problem:

Because phrases file is big it creates loads of iterations and makes script very slow.

> (700 patterns x 10 columns (separated by tab \t)) x 1000 of rows.

Solution:

To improve speed I would like to concat first 10 columns, and check if entire string contains at least one pattern. I can't figure out how to concat lines in FOR loop.

Working example:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{
FS=" *\t *";
IGNORECASE=1;

while(getline a < "'$phpath'") PATS["^.*"a".*$"]
}

{
    ok=1;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        for(p in PATS){
            if($i ~ p){
            ok=0
            }
        }
    }

} 
ok {print}' "$f" > "$newPath$filename"
```

My attempt:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{
    FS=" *\t *";
    IGNORECASE=1;

    while(getline a < "'$phpath'") PATS["^.*"a".*$"]
    }

    {
        phrase="";
        space=" ";
        ok=1;

        for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
            phrase = $space $phrase $i
        }

        for(p in PATS){
            if($phrase ~ p){
                ok=0
            }
        }

    } ok {print}' "$f" > "$newPath$filename"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk, you use `$` like a *dereferencing operator*, where `$x` means "give me the value of the column whose number is in variable `x`"

To get the first 10 columns into a string:

```
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        # not this => phrase = $space $phrase $i
        phrase = space phrase $i
    }
```

and

```
    for (p in PATS) {
        if (phrase ~ p) {   # <= no $
            ok = 0
            break           # no match, so break the loop early
        }
    }
```

awk uses variables like C, not like shell or perl

---

You might also try this:

```
gawk -v patternfile="$phpath" '
    BEGIN {
        FS = " *\t *"
        IGNORECASE = 1
        while ((getline a < patternfile) > 0)
            PATS["^.*"a".*$"]
    }
    {
        line = $0
        NF = 10         # this truncates the current record to 10 fields
        ok = 1
        for (p in PATS) 
            if ($0 ~ p) {
                ok = 0
                break
            }
        if (ok) 
            print line
    }
' "$f" > "$newPath$filename"
```

Comment: thank you for very clear explanation and suggested solution. Your code looks much more lightweight. Do I need a break when looping patterns in your suggested solution?

Comment: That will go into an infinite loop if it encounters an error reading patternfile since getline will return `-1`. You need `while ( (getline a < patternfile) > 0 )`, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. You can do the comparison without a loop by creating a `|`-separated string from patternfile instead of populating an array.

Comment: I have a gut feeling that looping with many small regexes *may* be faster than one gigantic regex. Would need to benchmark it though.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question but maybe to your problem.

I understand that your issue is about performance.

As I understand one of the major issues you have is that you are using RegEx. Let me explain my point. In AWK when you work with a regex like this: /MyRegExp/, you are using a compiled version of the RegEx so every time you need to check matching you only check it, but as you are using RegEx like this: "MyRegExp", this is compiled every time that you want to check if a string matches.

Are you really checking RegEx? Maybe you're not and the function 'index' is good enough for you.

Why don't you try to build a script and run it? Instead checking every line in the second file against the patterns loaded, you create a script like this:

```
/pattern1/{
    print
    next
}
/pattern2/{
    print
    next
}
/pattern3/{
    print
    next
}
...
...
```

And then run it with the second file. Anyway, I hope it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> while(getline a < "'$phpath'") PATS["^.*"a".*$"]
> ```

The RE `^.*"a".*$` is equivalent to `a`.  And instead of iterating over the patterns, you can state the OR condition directly with `|`.

If your input file is

```
every
good
boy
does
fine
```

your RE becomes `every|good|boy|does|fine` and your code is reduced to

```
$0 ~ pattern { 
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        if( $i ~ pattern ) { 
           print "$f" > "$newPath$filename" # what's $f?  
           break
        }
    }
}
```

That is, scan the whole line first.  If it finds something, iterate over the first 10 columns.  I bet that's faster than iterating over them unconditionally.

Comment: I need patterns because columns do not contain exact phrases.

for e.g:

`test my phrase test, test, test, test, test, test, test`

to capture `my phrase` I need regex.